# magmi not connecting simple products with configurable

Tags: php, magento, magmi

We have a webshop in magento, using magmi to import the products. i already got the products imported. there all configurable product with other simple products below it.

im importing the simple first then the configurable products.
i also enabled the plugin for the configurable item processor.

```
        [sku] => 00000001AI.100
        [name] => some name
        [brand] => somebrand
        [price] => 187.93
        [description] => descript
        [short_description] => short_description
        [categories] => category
        [simples_skus] => 00000001AI.100-Zwart-34,00000001AI.100-Zwart-36,
        [type] => configurable
        [attribute_set] => Producten
        [visibility] => 4
        [is_in_stock] => 1
        [manage_stock] => 1
        [status] => 1
```

**Simple products were created first.**

Extra information

- im using magmi datapump
  i use array's to build the import en then inject it with magmi ingest function.

Comment: Can you at least share what your CSV looks like/what you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this new information. I was actually asking for your **MAGMI** input CSV..

Comment: im using magmi datapump en ingest it through magmi api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're obviously missing the `configurable_attributes` field/column.

Comment: and you focused on `simple_skus` which is, ironically, optional. Maybe for your needs you need this as I see you're trying to add colors to the simple skus. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

NOTE it will be helpful if you are using magmi with csv files

I feel you have not added the configurable_attributes in your csv. I will suggest you to create separate csv for simple and configurable products.

let's take an example of shoe products, you have configurable products with different sizes than your simple products csv will have the size attribute(attribute name can be size or anything as per your requirement) and it can not be blank.

now come to configurable product csv it will have 2 extra fields (configurable_attributes and simples_skus).

configurable_attributes will have the value as size attribute or the name which you have in your simple product csv.

simples_skus will have comma separated sku of simple product which you want to associate with configurable product.

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable  the Configurable Item Processor by going to the configuration page of magmi : http://your_host/magmi_dir/web/magmi.php